# Notifying a service when property is changed

Tags: android

Is there a way to notify Android service when system property is changed?
As far as I understand there is no corresponding action to be used in intent-filter in manifest?

UPDATE: the service is not supposed to be running at the time of property change.

Comment: "when system property..." what do you mean with this ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody like when setprop is called

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886976/can-i-write-a-system-property-listener-in-android) ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody this requires the service to be running at the time of property change which is undesirable for my purposes